# Setting up a snippet in Visual Studio Code with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, textmate

```
{
    "Comment": {
        "prefix": "#",
        "body":  "<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/([^/]*\/[^/]*)$/$1/} -->"
    }
}
```

I have set up the about code snippet, the purpose is to add a comment that adds the file's base directory and file name `<!-- templates/base.html -->`
like this but discards the rest of the path.  I believe this is originally based on TextMate snippets.

[image]

I have tried everything but I can't get it to work, it's probably something silly but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Using just
`TM_FILEPATH`
without the regex results in
`<!-- /Users/johndoe/Sites/blog/blog/templates/base.html -->`

I used this https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets to find an example to base my code on. The example is this one:

```
${TM_FILENAME/(.*)\\..+$/$1/}
  |           |        | |
  |           |        | |-> no options
  |           |        |
  |           |        |-> references the contents of the first
  |           |             capture group
  |           |
  |           |-> regex to capture everything before
  |               the final `.suffix`
  |
  |-> resolves to the filename
```

Thanks to the ideas of the 2 commenters I was finally able to get it to work.

One commenter put me on track with the double backslashes to catch both Windows and Unix style slashes.

The other commenter suggested the square brackets.

Final result:

```
{
    "Comment": {
        "prefix": "#",
        "body":  "<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*[\\/](.*[\\/].*)$/$1/} -->",
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that's it

Comment: But only the square brackets and 2 backslashes per slash were needed that was the trick.

Comment: Cool. Took me a while. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try it with a character class that takes account of both path separator types and helps us to escape properly at the same time:

```
{
    "Comment": {
        "prefix": "#",
        "body":  [  
            "<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*[\\/](.*[\\/].*)$$/$1/} -->",
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: The final regex that worked after stripping the redundant backslashes was this:

.*[\\/](.*[\\/].*)$

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
"Comment": {
    "prefix": "#",
    "body":  [

      "<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*\\\\(.*\\\\.*)$$/$1/} -->",

      "<!-- ${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\\\(.*)$/$1/}/${TM_FILENAME} -->",
    ]
},
```

Those two lines in the body should be equivalent.  That works for the Windows directory style, like :

```
 c:\Users\Mark\asdf\experimental\src\js\main.js
```

Since your path.separators are `/`  try something like:

```
"<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*\/(.*\.*)$/$1/} -->", 
"<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*\\/(.*\\.*)$/$1/} -->",
"<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*\\\/(.*\\\.*)$/$1/} -->",
"<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*\\\\/(.*\\\\.*)$/$1/} -->",
```

I just don't know how many backslashes you will need (and I can't test it here) for your OS.

Comment: Thank you for testing it but unfortunately, none of the examples you posted are working for me.

I'm on OSX by the way

Comment: See edit, you will probably have to use one of he later three options if you are on macOS.  That is what I meant by adding backslashes.

Comment: I tried by adding backslashes but it didn't help, I'm starting to think this might be a bug on MacOS.

Comment: Ok tried again with your suggestions this is the result:
`<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*/(.**)$//} -->`

`<!-- post_new.html -->`

`<!-- /Users/stofke/Sites/blog/blog/templates/post_new.html -->`

`<!-- /Users/stofke/Sites/blog/blog/templates/post_new.html -->`

Note it does the output in reverse order. So the last suggestion is the first result and vice versa.

Comment: Ok I tried the suggestion of  wp78de which added more backslashes and it worked

answer is: 

`"body":  "<!-- ${TM_FILEPATH/.*[\\/](.*[\\/].*)$/$1/} -->"`

Comment: It was actually the square brackets that did it

Comment: Well, I don't think the brackets in your answer don't actually do anything.  The only reason wp78de used them was to handle both path.separators as I mentioned.  One is \\\ and the other is \\/.  If you are not concerned about handling both, the brackets gain you no functionality.  And they definitely are not needed on my Windows machine where I did test the code.  So some implementation bug on vscode's part perhaps.  I'm glad you got it working but you should know it shouldn't have been because of the brackets.  If someone can correct that I would love to learn it.

Comment: I know it shouldn't matter but it did the trick. As you said and I already thought this might be a bug in Visual Code Studio.  Probably due to the fact the coders work on Windows.

Comment: I'll check if I can post this to their bug tracker.

Comment: Actually if you watch any of their video demos or talks they mostly seem to be using macs.