# VSCode Regex Snippet

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I'm trying to write VSCode snippet to populate a remote repo path using the local Windows repo path as the basis but struggling a little with the syntax, can anybody help?

```
"MetaData Snippet": {
    "prefix": "META",
    "body": [
      "<#",
      "    .SYNOPSIS",
      "        ${1:Enter general synopsis of the type of script}",
      "",
      "    .DESCRIPTION",
      "        ${2:Short description of what the script will do}",
      "",
      "    .PARAMETER ${3:ParameterNameHere}",
      "        ${4:Description of the parameter}",
      "",
      "    .EXAMPLE",
      "        ${5:Example of how to use the code and also expected output}",
      "",
      "    .NOTES",
      "        VSTS:   ${7:$TM_FILEPATH/(.)(:\\)(.*)(\\TSO NH)//g}",
      "",
      "        | Author            | QC                | VSTS Story ID     | Release Date  |",
      "        -----------------------------------------------------------------------------",
      "        | ${8:Author Name}  | ${9:Name of reviewer} | ${10:Story Number} | $CURRENT_DATE/$CURRENT_MONTH/$CURRENT_YEAR_SHORT      |",
      "#>"
    ],
    "description": "MetaData Snippet"
  }
```

EXAMPLE PATH: `c:\Users\USERNAME\git\Cloud and Automation\.vscode\test.ps1`

Essentially I want to chop out `c:\Users\USERNAME\git\` and the remainder I want to replace the `\` characters with `/`.

I know my syntax is wrong but I'm not sure I understand regex well enough and can't figure it out :(

To summarize I want to turn:

```
c:\Users\USERNAME\git\Cloud and Automation\.vscode\test.ps1
```

into:

```
Cloud and Automation/.vscode/test.ps1
```

Comment: If you'd like help specifically with the regex, simply put in the example line you are starting with, and what you'd like it transformed to.  Are you just trying to replace \ with / in a string?

Comment: This is what I'm going for...

Current: c:\Users\USERNAME\git\Cloud and Automation\.vscode\test.ps1

Result: Cloud and Automation/.vscode/test.ps1

Comment: looks good.  I don't know VS but could whip up a 4 line solution in python fast, but I suspect somebody with VS skills is going to answer this shortly.  If not, leave a comment and I can put my python answer in and you can see how the regex works.

Comment: Yeah I think that would be helpful, at least so that I can understand the logic and may be able to figure out from there.

This is where I've gotten to with the regex expression: (^.*Cloud)|(\\) This seems to match 2 groups (Group1: 'file path' & Group2: '\'), I'm just failing at the transform.

Comment: Cool, I'll put an answer in

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\\\(.*)\\\\(.*)$/$1\\/$2/}/${TM_FILENAME}"
```

and see [escaping in vscode snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688947/setting-up-a-snippet-in-visual-studio-code-with-regex).  You do have a `.` in there for `.vscode`, so you might have to accommodate for that as well - just add an escaped period to the second capture group `(\..*)` or more backslashes there but you might not need that at all.

Comment: This is pretty damn close! The only issue I found was that it looks like it's creating a capture group for every group of characters between a pair of backslashes and the transform puts it back without slashes. This works great until you navigate to a different folder path depth and use it.

Do you know of a way to capture "Beginning <---> git\" then remove, capture remaining '\' and replace with '/'? I may be completely misunderstanding regex

Comment: It gets the last two directories from TM_DIRECTORY each in their own capture group so that the path separator can be not captured but replaced by /, and then adds the filename to the end.  I thought that was what you wanted?  And I don't understand your question in the comment: "Beginning....git\?

Answer (score -1):

Although this in python and not VS, you can see the regex in action.  As per the OP's request in the comments here is the example in python.

```
import re

data = r"c:\Users\USERNAME\git\Cloud and Automation\.vscode\test.ps1"
path = re.sub(r".*git\\", "", data)   #strip up to git
fixed_path = re.sub(r"\\", "/", path) #replace backslashes with slashes
print(fixed_path)
```

Note that I'm escaping the `\` that might be part of what you are running into.  I'm opting to strip the string instead of trying to capture parts of it, sometimes it's just easier that way :)

Output:

```
Cloud and Automation/.vscode/test.ps1
```