# Regex with capturing group for vs code snippets

Tags: regex, code-snippets

I am trying to have a VS code snippets.For generating java class.I am terrible with regex. As explained in [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)  followed the instruction.

what i am trying is to extract the package name from my project path 
    `/home/bspl/Projects/SpringBoot/mdmssa/src/main/java/com/mdmssa/controller`

which should be like

`com.mdmssa.controller`

the keyword here is `java` which will remain same in every project.
Till now i came up with this following another thread in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50688947/setting-up-a-snippet-in-visual-studio-code-with-regex)

     `"${TM_FILEPATH/.*[\\/](.*[\\/].*)$/$1/}"`

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: java\\/(.+) -> i think you can try this use the value of captured group split it with / and replace by .

Comment: thanks that gave me a direction.. now with `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*[\\/]java\\/(.*[\\/].*)$/$1/}`  i can capture the group but was not able to do a transformation on captured group i.e `com/mdmssa/controller` has to be transformed to `com.mdmssa.controller` Any idea on that..

Comment: Now you can simply replace the / with . using replace method

Comment: Try `path.replaceAll(".+/(\\w+)/(\\w+)/(\\w+$)", "$1.$2.$3");` On the example path you give, it returns `com.mdmssa.controller`

Comment: Did something like `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*[\\/]java\\/(.*[\\/].*)$/${1/[\\]/\./}/}` and it doesn't work..  and  regex in `path.replaceAll(".+/(\\w+)/(\\w+)/(\\w+$)", "$1.$2.$3")` will work in most of my projects only drawback it is limited to 3 level of directory..

Comment: came up with this `${TM_DIRECTORY/.*.java\\/?(\\w+)\\/?(\\w+)\\/?(\\w+).*$/$1.$2.$3/}` work in most of cases.. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work

```
${TM_DIRECTORY/.+java\\/|([^\\/]+)|(\\/)/$1${2:+.}/g}
```

With global flag we have 3 groups that transform

1. `.+java\\/` - everything before and including last `java/` transforms to empty string
2. `([^\\/]+)` - names between `/` after `java/` doesn't transform
3. `(\\/)` - `/` transforms to `.` through `:+` which transforms capture if it is present